# Lazy Evaluation Explained

Tags: scala

**Update**: Updated the code with the usage on both constructors, basically what I m confused with is, what is the difference between `Cons` and `Stream.cons`. P.S. this example is from chapter 5 from the Book *Functional Programming in Scala*.

So can anyone explain to me why the following lazy evaluation is not working as intended? The output of my Scala worksheet is

```
One
res0: Int = 1
One
res1: Int = 2
One
res2: Int = 3
One
res3: Int = 4
One
res4: Int = 5
One
res5: Int = 6
```

Clear this is not the intended output, as due to lazy evaluation `One` should only be printed once and `i` should be incremented only once, but this does not seem to be the case. I am missing something but can't see it, any fresh pair of eyes minds lending a hand?

```
sealed trait Stream[+A] {
  def toList: List[A] = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def go(s: Stream[A], acc: List[A]): List[A] = s match {
      case Cons(h,t) => go(t(), h() :: acc)
      case _ => acc
    }
    go(this, List()).reverse
  }
}
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty
    else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}

var i = 0
val nonLazy = Cons(
  () => { println("One"); i+=1; i }, 
  () => Cons(
    () => { println("Two"); i+=2; i }, 
    () => Empty))
nonLazy.h
nonLazy.h
nonLazy.h

var i = 0
val lazy = Stream.cons(
  () => { println("One"); i+=1; i }, 
  Stream.cons(
    () => { println("Two"); i+=2; i }, 
    Empty)).toList
lazy.head
lazy.head
lazy.head
lazy.head
lazy.head
lazy.head
```

Comment: Since you have `=> A` in `cons` I assume you want to pass an expression of type `A`, not a function, like `System.cons({println("One"); println(i); i+=1; i}, ...`. Then you don't need `()`, just `stream.head` and it will work as expected.

Comment: I get what you say Victor and that does work as intended, but doesn't that defeat the entire purpose of it all, its like you applied the function yourself, and returning the results of the function to the Stream.

Comment: Also with your suggestion I can just remove the `lazy val head` and `lazy val tail` and would have the same effect as `Cons(() => hd, () => tl)`

Comment: @VictorMoroz This should be an answer (especially since the existing answers are wrong).

Comment: @MrX No. Try it: removing the lazy vals will result in `println` being called every time you call `lazy.h()`.

Comment: indeed was getting confused because of the toList method which was transforming the Stream to a List

Answer (score 2):

```
lazy val head = hd
```

as you didn't specify type of `head`, it will be `() => Int`, and every time you fetch the head, `hd` being evaluated, `i` increased and increased

I think you want to calculate `hd` and store the value in `Stream.cons` function, so you need to explicit specify the type:

```
lazy val head: A = hd
```

so does the `tail` variable.

Comment: I thought he might mean this, but if that's the case, then `case class Cons` has the entirely wrong type declarations (though that may be due to them being unintentionally inferred that way, rather than him meaning that).

Comment: Wait, how does it help? `head` is already `A`, only `A` is `()=> Int` if called this way. I would assume `System.cons({println("One"); println(i); i+=1; i}, ...` instead so `A` is `Int`. Declaring  `head: A` doesn't help, not when I try it.

Comment: Indeed what Victor said is actually correct, specifying type to head did not do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think you're forgetting what `hd` is - namely, a `function0` that returns an Int, or to use the shorthand, `() => Int`.

When you call this:

`stream.head()`

What this does is:

1. Retrieve `stream.head` (which is a function, and thus has an `apply()` method that can be called, which will print 'One', increment `i` by two, and return `i`.
2. Execute that function, because `()` is the way that Scala makes it nice and easy to call the aforementioned `apply()` method.

If you don't want the function executed, try the following:

```
stream.head
stream.head
stream.head
stream.head
stream.head
stream.head
```

This will return:

```
res0: () => Int = <function0>
res1: () => Int = <function0>
res2: () => Int = <function0>
res3: () => Int = <function0>
res4: () => Int = <function0>
res5: () => Int = <function0>
```

The `val` is indeed lazy - it's the same function every time - but you're then executing it 6 times!

Comment: What I wanted to do is to avoid the function running more than once, in the case you specified all that happening is I m getting the same reference to the same function without it ever being run, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @MrX In that case you'll need to modify your `Cons` case class to use `A` and `Stream[A]` rather than `() =>`'s that return those.

Comment: I'm missing something here though, if I do so I loose the scope of having 2 constructors, Cons and cons, **Cons** should not make use of lazy evaluation  and should evaluate the function every time, while **cons**, should make use of lazy evaluation and run the function just once

Comment: Let me ask you this - are you trying to have it so it's storing an actual function in `hd` and `tl`, and consequently in `head` and `tail`, or are you wanting those to be of type `A` and `Stream[A]`?

Comment: I see what your saying, but what I m trying to do it through lazy evaluation is to transform the high order function, into another higher order function which just return the result of the first time it was run.

`() => {println("One"); println(i); i+=1; i}`

get transformed to 

`() => 2`

due to it being lazy and just ran once

Comment: In that case, I think what you want is more like this: `lazy val headEval = hd(); lazy val head = () => {headEval};`  Takes the result of `hd()`, stores it, and constructs a new function that only returns the result of the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `Stream.cons(()=>{println("One"); i+=1; i}, Stream.cons(()=>{println("Two"); i+=2; i}, Empty))`, you'll need to fix its type:

```
def cons[A](hd: () => A, tl: () => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
  lazy val head = hd()
  lazy val tail = tl()
  Cons(() => head, () => tail)
}
```

And to access it, you need

```
val stream = Stream.cons(()=>{println("One"); i+=1; i}, Stream.cons(()=>{println("Two"); i+=2; i}, Stream.Empty)) // won't print anything
stream.h() // will print "One" and return 1
stream.h() // will return 1 without printing anything
stream.h() // will return 1 without printing anything
```

Using `toList` will stop you from actually seeing laziness.

Comment: This together with @VictorMoroz answer explains it I think

Comment: Note that his solution also works fine. You can see its laziness in the same way.